# Dual Monitor Problems with X11

Tags: xorg

After spending 2 day researching this problem, learning about RandR and Xinerama and lots of other stuff. I've reached a dead-end and so felt that I should ask here. Basically, I can't get a dual monitor setup working the way I want it to. Here's a breakdown of the problem:

SETUP: I have an HP Pavillion G series laptop running Slackware 13.37. I have an external monitor: Dell 2000FP. Window manager is xfce. I want to use both monitors for one 'Desktop' (i.e. one continuous screen, where I can slide a window from the laptop monitor to the dell monitor, etc). I've done this before with other laptops, and in fact, with this setup if I boot into windows rather than linux, it handles it automatically. But in the slackware version I'm using there are odd problems. I'm posting my xorg.conf file at the end of this question since it's probably relevant.

PROBLEM: With the xorg.conf file that I've posted the result is mostly OK. I indeed have a continuous desktop between the two monitors. The resolution on the laptop is correct, but the resolution on the external monitor is 800x600 where it should be 1600x1200. There is a gui interface for the 'Display' variable that, when launched gives me back an error: RandR extension missing on display ":0.0".

According the research I've done, the problem is a conflict between Xinerama and RandR. In my first xorg.conf file I had both of them "ON". So, I commented out the "option "Xinerama" "ON" line, and several things happened:
1) the resolution remained the same on both screeens
2) I no longer got an error message, but the 'Display' variable gui didn't have "1600x1200" as an option for the external monitor (even though that's the only resolution listed in xorg.conf). 
3) The 'screen' will let the mouse travel between monitors as if it's one large 'screen', but WILL NOT allow windows to be dragged from one monitor to the other! (I really don't get that).

Basically, I just need to have the two monitors have one screen, both with the proper resolution.
I'm posting my xorg.conf file.

```
Section "Module"
   Load        "dbe"  
   Load        "type1"
   Load        "freetype"
   Load        "glx"     
   SubSection  "extmod"
     Option    "omit xfree86-dga" 
   EndSubSection
 EndSection

 Section "Files"
   ModulePath  "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/misc" 
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/util" 
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" 
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/TTF" 
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" 
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/Speedo"
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi:unscaled"
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi:unscaled"   
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi"
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi"
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/encodings"
   FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/cyrillic"
 EndSection

Section "Module"
Load  "glx"
Load  "extmod"
Load  "record"
Load  "dri2"
Load  "dbe"
Load  "dri"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
Option      "BlankTime"    "0" 
Option      "StandbyTime"  "0"
Option      "SuspendTime"  "0"
Option      "OffTime"      "0"
Option      "Xinerama"     "ON"
#Option     "RandR"    "ON"
Option  "DefaultServerLayout" "DualScreens"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   Identifier   "Keyboard0"
   Driver   "kbd"
 Option "CoreKeyboard"
 Option "SendCoreEvent" "1"  
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   Identifier   "Mouse0"
   Driver   "mouse"
   Option "Protocol"    "PS/2"
   Option "Device"      "/dev/mouse"
   Option "CorePointer"
   Option "SendCoreEvent" "1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor" # laptop
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "SEC"
    ModelName    "4251"
    Option "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor" # external monitor
  Identifier "Monitor1"
  VendorName "DELL"
  ModelName  "DELL 2000FP"
  HorizSync 31.0-80.0
  VertRefresh 56.0-76.0
  Option "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device" # laptop
Identifier  "Card0"
Driver      "radeon"
Screen 0    
Option "Monitor-LVDS"  "Monitor0"    # fbe2
EndSection

Section "Device" # external monitor
  Identifier "Card1"
  Driver     "radeon"
  Screen 1
  Option "Monitor-VGA" "Monitor1"    # fbe2
EndSection

Section "Screen"
 Identifier  "Screen 0" # laptop display
 Device      "Card0"
 Monitor     "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth 16
SubSection "Display"
  Depth     8
      Modes "1366x768"      
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
  Depth     15
      Modes "1366x768"      
EndSubSection   
Subsection "Display"
      Depth    16
      Modes "1366x768"
  EndSubsection
  Subsection "Display"
    Depth    24
    Modes "1366x768"
  EndSubsection     
EndSection

Section "Screen"
 Identifier  "Screen 1" # Dell 2000FP
 Device      "Card1"
 Monitor     "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth 16
SubSection "Display"
  Depth     8
      Modes "1600x1200"     
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
  Depth     15
      Modes "1600x1200"     
EndSubSection       
Subsection "Display"
      Depth    16
      Modes "1600x1200"
    EndSubsection
    Subsection "Display"
      Depth    24
      Modes "1600x1200"
    EndSubsection       
EndSection

 Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier  "DualScreens"
   Screen 0 "Screen 0" 0 0
   Screen 1 "Screen 1" RightOf "Screen 0"
   InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
   InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection
```